# Jquery .autocomplete, how to add more GET request parameters

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Cant understand how to add more parameters into source request. Below is alredy working example i use in many places.

```
$( function() {

    $( "#sn" ).autocomplete({
        source: "serial_search.php",
     minLength: 0,
      appendTo: "#newcaseform",
       data: 'site_id=sss' ,  
       select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#project").val( ui.item.сaddr );
        $("#site_code").val( ui.item.site_code );
        $("#site_id").val(ui.item.site_id);
        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.comp + "<br>" + item.addr + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  } );
```

I tried this simple way

```
source: "serial_search.php" +$("#site_id").val(),
```

did not work(

Comment: $_GET is a PHP var and therefore can not be access through JavaScript. Does `#site_id` get its value from a PHP page?

Comment: not exactly. i need to get current value from #site_id input box and send it to php while .autocomplete is working